# Cannot compile java following upgrade to Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, java, eclipse, openjdk

Before I upgraded Kubuntu I could compile in eclipse. Eclipse now says:

```
The project was not built since its build path was incomplete.
Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path.
```

I am not sure what to add to the build path for the standard API.

I used to be able to compile using make. Now I get errors citing other standard class files missing (Throwable, Iterable, List, ...)

I was using `openjdk7` (though I had `openjdk8` installed too and was happily using `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to switch).
I am now trying to use `openjdk8`.

I noticed JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH are not set. I tried setting JAVA_HOME to `/usr/lib/jvm/java/java-8-openjdk-amd64/`, but that did not help.

I am not sure what I should set CLASSPATH too.

Comment: I fixed compilation from the command line with "sudo apt-get --reinstall install openjdk-8-jdk-headless" "sudo apt-get --reinstall install openjdk-8-jre-headless"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed compilation from the command line with

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install openjdk-8-jdk-headless`

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install openjdk-8-jre-headless`

I fixed Eclipse by deleting "~/.eclipse".